# How to handle an dynamic array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variable-length-array

I want to show up the names of the members of an array "path" in my console.

```
console.log("start: ", path[0].name, "second: ", path[1].name, "third: ", path[2]name, ....)
```

But the problem is, that my array always changes it's size (clicking algorithm), that means sometimes it has the lenght 4 or sometimes 8 ect.
 How can i adjust the `console.log` code to this dynamic array?
Thanks so much!

Comment: check length of array and use for loop

Comment: thanks so much to all of you....so many different suggestions, i don't know where to start  :)

Comment: wherever you want but don't start from nina's answer  .she is little advanced.

Comment: nina's version is crazy ;) i am a beginner and i cannot even read her second line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var path = ['Prit', 'Bab', 'Nav']
var item = ["first","second", "third"]; 
for (i = 0; i < path.length;i++){
    console.log(item[i] + ":" + path[i])
}
```

Comment: Ok, now it works on my console. But is there a chance to make them appear on screen like this? 1. element: name1, 2. element: name2, 3. element: name3 .........

Comment: @DerickKolln just change console.log to document.write

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
path.forEach((each, i)=>{
   console.log ("item" + i+ ':' + each.name );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for single line result set ...

```
var result = "";
for (var i = 0, len = path.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (i !== 0) {
    result += ", ";
  }
  result += (i + 1) + ": " + path[i].name;
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
/* Console Array */
var consoleArray = new Array;

/* Names */
var path = [
    {name: 'bob'},
    {name: 'jimmy'},
    {name: 'chris'},
    {name: 'alexander'},
    {name: 'mark'}
];

/* Loop */
for(var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    consoleArray.push((i + 1) + ': ' + path[i].name);
}

/* Console Log */
console.log(consoleArray.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6, you could use [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var path = [{ name: 'Jo'}, { name: 'John'}, { name: 'Jane'}];
console.log(...path.map((a, i) => (i ? i + 1 : 'Start') + ': ' + a.name));
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a for loop here , ie,

```
for (var i=0;i<path.length;i++) {
   console.log("item no "+ i +": " + path[i]);
}
```